# Is 'peasant' generally considered derogatory?

Tags: american-english, british-english, pejorative-language, subcontinental-english

Is ***peasant*** when used in  general to describe a  ***modern*** socioeconomic class considered to be derogatory?

Apparently there is no issue when talking about European history...

I read in the [Brtitannica online](https://www.britannica.com/topic/peasantry)

> ***peasant***, any member of ***a class of persons who till the soil as small landowners or as agricultural labourers***. The term peasant originally referred to small-scale agriculturalists in Europe in historic times, but many other societies, both past and present, have had a peasant class.

Here in Latin-America, approximately 60% of the population come from families squatting and often squabbling over  a parcel of land mostly insufficient to provide sustenance for a family any larger that 4 or 5 people. [Hence the constant migration to the North...]

In Spanish, we often call these people *campesinos*...not when addressing them face to face, but in discussion of the people in terms of economic classes. Some people say this is a  derogatory form of

[field hand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/field%20hand)

(which describes workers who work  the fields, *but  would not include those owning their own land.)*

---

This could be an insult...the most famous example I can think of is [from the de Palma film*.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7Np_G-KV9A)

Is 'peasant' usually considered derogatory when discussing the socioeconomic class?

Or is it just obsolete in this usage?

---

[*Scarface (1983)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarface_(1983_film))

Comment: It seems to me that "peasant" is basically neutral in societies and ages that have a peasant class, but in societies and ages without "peasants", it is pejorative.

Comment: It's complex. A "[peasant blouse](https://www.etsy.com/uk/market/peasant_blouse)" isn't pejorative, but something like "[peasant mentality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peasant_mentality)" probably is. If it's intended as an insult (as in Scarface), it's derogatory, but it's also used factually in social science, and in lots of set phrases whose connotation varies.

Answer (score 3):

In the contemporary West, absolutely. (I've heard it quite often in every day urban usage.) However, there may be some exceptions in communal societies as in, for example, communes in rural France where its older definition may still hold sway. See both: [Peasant (noun) 1 and 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peasant)...  And from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peasant#:%7E:text=In%20a%20colloquial%20sense%2C%20%22peasant%22%20often%20has%20a,referring%20to%20farm%20laborers%20in%20the%20developing%20world):

> In some contexts, "peasant" has a pejorative meaning, even when referring to farm laborers...

Also, from John Lennon's '[Working Class Hero](https://www.songfacts.com/lyrics/john-lennon/working-class-hero)',

> And you think you're so clever and classless and free
> But you're still [expletive] peasants as far as I can see